# Why am I getting a "free(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)" error? C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, overloading, free

I am trying to overload a the = operator to copy and eventually swap two deques?

However I am getting the 
`free(): invalid pointer`
`Aborted (core dumped)`

error when the while loop exits. Everything run fine when the `tempDeque.display();` function call is commented out.

Here is the block of code for operator overloading:

```
class Resizeable_deque{
    private:
        T* array;
        int front;
        int back;
        int deque_size;
        int capacity;
        int initial_capacity;

    public:
        // Resizeable_deque();

        //accessors
        Resizeable_deque(int n=10) //done constructor
        {
            if (n==10)
            {
                array = new T[10];
                capacity = 10;
                initial_capacity = 10;
                front = -1;
                back = 0;
                deque_size = 0;
                // cout <<  "Capacity = " << capacity << endl;
                // cout << "OK!";

            }

            else if  (n<=10)
            {
                array = new T [n];
                capacity = n;
                initial_capacity = n;
                front = -1;
                back = 0;
                deque_size = 0;
                // cout <<  "Capacity = " << capacity << endl;

                // cout << "OK!!";
            }
        }

        ~Resizeable_deque(); //done destructor

        //accessors
        T* getArray() const;
        T getFront() const; // done get front element
        T getBack() const; //done get last element
        int size() const; //done get the size of the queue
        int getCapacity() const; //done get the current capacity of queue
        int getInitialCapacity() const;

        //data member setters
        // void setArray(T* newArray);
        // void setfront(int newFront);
        // void setBack (int newBack);
        // void setSize (int newSize);
        // void setCapacity (int newCapacity);
        // void setInitialCapacity(int newInitialCapacity);


        //state check functions
        bool full()  const;
        bool empty() const; //done check if empty
        T display() const;

        //mutators
        void push_front (const T e);
        void push_back (const T e);
        void pop_front();
        void pop_back();
        void pop_front_back();
        void resizeDeque(float resizefactor, int newsize);
        void swap(Resizeable_deque tempDeque);
        Resizeable_deque operator=(Resizeable_deque b)
        {
            cout <<"B:";
            b.display();
            cout << "Back: " << b.getBack() << endl;
            int bSize = b.size();
            Resizeable_deque<string> tempDeque(b.getCapacity());
            while (!b.empty())
            {
                tempDeque.push_back(b.getFront());
                // b.display();
                b.pop_front();
                cout<< "popped!" << endl;
                tempDeque.display();
                cout <<  "back is: " << b.getFront() << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;
            }

            //end of loop call swap
        };
        void clear();

};
```

Comment: The problem could be in the prototype of the operator. Can you paste it with your class definition, please ?

Comment: I suspect you have undefined behaviour somewhere in code that's not shown.  Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I can not add a comment so I write here.

I noticed that you use `operater new[]` to allocate memory, have you used `free()` on a pointer which you allocated it with `new[]`? This may cause the error.

If not, check out if you use `free()` on a pointer that not original(have you ++ or -- on it and change its offset?).

Otherwise, check out if you did some out-of-bounds accesses.

May these will help you.

Comment: I can not run your code, so I can only give some advice.

Answer (score 0):

As you're passing by value (into e.g. the swap function), your copy constructor will be called. As you've not defined a copy constructor a default one will be created for you. That copy constructor will just copy the pointer value of `array` which means you'll have 2 instances pointing to the same dynamically allocated memory. When both of those destructors run it'll free the memory twice which causes undefined behavoir, which shows up as the error you see.

You are basically breaking the rule of [0/3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

An easy fix would be to make array `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` which will cause build errors until you fix your issue.